# Search for a Name and return the most recent month with data

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm looking to search a staff members name from a list in Column A, and have another cell return only the most recent column header as a date, where a value is present.

I've tried `=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(ISBLANK(INDEX(B2:B12,MATCH(H7,$A$2:$A$12,0)):INDEX($F$2:$F$12,MATCH(H7,$A$2:$A$12,0))),"",$B$1:$F$1))`

This works, but it returns ALL headers where ANY value is present, not just the most recent date.

I'd love the tool to look like this

[image: I'd love the tool to look like this]

With a dropdown or other auto-fill field like this

[image: With a dropdown or other auto-fill field like this]

And here's what I've tried

[image: And here's what I've tried]

Any help is hugely appreciated thanks all!

Comment: Your *I'd love the tool to look like this* screenshot shows 'Jan 2021, Apr 2021' as your expected result. Can you clarify what it should actually be?

Comment: It should show Apr 2021 - the most current date in all the headers.

Comment: Are the headers proper dates, or text entries? You can test this using, for example, the `ISNUMBER` function, which will return `TRUE` if they are proper (numeric) dates.

Comment: I could actually do either... Whatever gives me a better formula

Comment: Have amended my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the headers are proper, Excel-recognised (i.e. numeric) dates:

`=MAX(IF(A2:A12=H7,IF(B2:F12<>"",B1:F1)))`

Format the resulting entry in the date format desired.